# Could I create a random url in node.js that points to another base url

Tags: node.js

Iam trying to get a shareable different links pointing to one base link
I have tried using random-url and UUID ,
But everytime I want to create a new url I want it to point to the base url.
May I please get some help

Comment: You can store the new URL and its corresponding Base URL in the Database.

Comment: what? what do you mean random url? and which base url?

Comment: Are you just trying to design tiny url use case or something else? Please elaborate on your question with specific Usecase and requirement detail, will get answers in no time :)